# Getting data from Webserver

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have a very simple webservice which is hosted on IIS, if you call any webmethod this basically throws some exception. There is third party application install in the same system where webservice hosted which intercept webmethod and get all information about unhandled exception (like method name, exceptiontype, stacktrace, code etc). Anyone who needs this exception info can subscribe for the eventobject with third party application. So I wrote event subscription code in IIS process itself.

So flow is like this, test client will call webmethod which basically throws some exception, third party application catches those exception and whoever subscribe for exceptioninfo will get those information in XML format.

Now I want that XML information to be accessed in my test client, is there any way to achieve this? I am not sure if this is feasible also or not as I am new to webservice world and please excuse me if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So when you're using the 3rd party, I'm assuming it's a module that's capturing all exceptions? Unless you can hook into that module to change the output to the client, it's likely that this cannot be done. Some modules allow you to override their default behavior.

Comment: Yes, 3rd module is capturing all exception. They have given API through which I can get all information. Only thing is that I need those information back to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solution for this problem, 
1) Using HttpModule edit the Http response and add the exception info xml in the response itself. 
2) have different exe which will run in background and subscribe for the exception info events using API provided by 3rd Party application. Once the exe receive exception information for any failed transaction, exe will write the same information in some shared storage. In my case I am using Azure Table Storage.